# MessageReference author when the message was deleted?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Given the situation :

**Guy 1** : Message X

**Guy 2** (Replying to Message X) : Message Y

**Guy 2** : *Deletes Message X*

With this, I would like to know how to retrieve the author of Message X in my bot, given the message is deleted and that the only information I have is that Guy 2 replied to him.

```
    if message.reference is not None:
        message_replied = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.reference.message_id)
        print(message_replied.author)
```

This does work for when the message is not deleted, but once deleted there is nothing showing up.

Thanks

Comment: That's simple : you can't. When a message a deleted, an event is triggered, then it is permanently removed. If you want to reuse the deleted message, you must save it somewhere when the deletion event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
   print(message.author)
```

Use `@client.event` if you use `client`. If you use cogs, replace `@bot.event` with `@commands.Cog.listener()`. [API Reference here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message_delete#discord.on_message_delete)